# submitting spark job to mesos cluster using java driver code

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I am trying to submit a spark job via a java driver to mesos cluster. There are no firewalls active and the mesos console shows 8GB ram available and 3 cores available. Yet I get "check cluster UI to see if enough resources are available"

Heres the code

```
           SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
           conf.setMaster(mesosmasterstring);


            conf.setAppName("demotask1");
            conf.setJars(scalaJarList);
            Properties sparkProps = FileLoader
                    .load(EnvironmentConstants.SPARK_PROPS_FILE_PATH);

            Set<Object> propNames = (sparkProps.keySet());
            for (Object kobj : propNames) {
                conf.set(kobj.toString().trim(),
                        sparkProps.getProperty(kobj.toString()).trim());

            }

//I have set the following via the code above:
//spark.executor.uri=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/minimo-dev2/spark/spark-//1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz 



        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
```

**My Webserver Log on which the driver process runs**

2015-08-20 15:56:04,981 WARN  [TaskSchedulerImpl] - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

2015-08-20 15:56:05,974 DEBUG [TaskSchedulerImpl] - parentName: , name: TaskSet_0, runningTasks: 0

2015-08-20 15:56:06,975 DEBUG [TaskSchedulerImpl] - parentName: , name: TaskSet_0, runningTasks: 0

2015-08-20 15:56:07,975 DEBUG [TaskSchedulerImpl] - parentName: , name: TaskSet_0, runningTasks: 0

2015-08-20 15:56:11,979 DEBUG [TaskSchedulerImpl] - parentName: , name: TaskSet_0, runningTasks: 0

2015-08-20 15:56:12,979 DEBUG [TaskSchedulerImpl] - parentName: , name: TaskSet_0, runningTasks: 0
2015-08-20 15:56:15,692 DEBUG [BlockManagerMasterActor] - [actor] received message ExpireDeadHosts from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/BlockManagerMaster#1596206704]

2015-08-20 15:56:15,693 DEBUG [BlockManagerMasterActor] - [actor] handled message (0.036696 ms) ExpireDeadHosts from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/BlockManagerMaster#1596206704]

2015-08-20 15:56:17,982 DEBUG [TaskSchedulerImpl] - parentName: , name: TaskSet_0, runningTasks: 0

2015-08-20 15:56:18,983 DEBUG [TaskSchedulerImpl] - parentName: , name: TaskSet_0, runningTasks: 0

2015-08-20 15:56:19,981 WARN  [TaskSchedulerImpl] - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

**Mesos Master.ip**

I0820 15:56:10.687042 32074 master.cpp:4290] Sending 1 offers to framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000 (demotask1) at scheduler-62a62438-bb19-4740-8428-7d632c958ef8@driverHost:33527

I0820 15:56:10.689906 32074 master.cpp:2884] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-O934 ] for framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000 (demotask1) at scheduler-62a62438-bb19-4740-8428-7d632c958ef8@driverHost:33527

I0820 15:56:10.690024 32074 hierarchical.hpp:761] Recovered cpus(*):1; mem(*):2735; disk(*):4031; ports(*):[31000-32000] (total: cpus(*):1; mem(*):2735; disk(*):4031; ports(*):[31000-32000], allocated: ) on slave 20150817-195212-2955812780-5050-29267-S0 from framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000
I0820 15:56:11.688359 32075 master.cpp:4290] Sending 1 offers to framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000 (demotask1) at scheduler-62a62438-bb19-4740-8428-7d632c958ef8@driverHost:33527

I0820 15:56:11.690852 32075 master.cpp:2884] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-O935 ] for framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000 (demotask1) at scheduler-62a62438-bb19-4740-8428-7d632c958ef8@driverHost:33527

I0820 15:56:11.690968 32075 hierarchical.hpp:761] Recovered cpus(*):1; mem(*):2735; disk(*):4031; ports(*):[31000-32000] (total: cpus(*):1; mem(*):2735; disk(*):4031; ports(*):[31000-32000], allocated: ) on slave 20150817-195212-2955812780-5050-29267-S1 from framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000
I0820 15:56:13.690409 32077 master.cpp:4290] Sending 1 offers to framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000 (demotask1) at scheduler-62a62438-bb19-4740-8428-7d632c958ef8@driverHost:33527

I0820 15:56:13.692711 32077 master.cpp:2884] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-O936 ] for framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000 (demotask1) at scheduler-62a62438-bb19-4740-8428-7d632c958ef8@driverHost:33527

I0820 15:56:13.692827 32077 hierarchical.hpp:761] Recovered cpus(*):1; mem(*):2735; disk(*):4031; ports(*):[31000-32000] (total: cpus(*):1; mem(*):2735; disk(*):4031; ports(*):[31000-32000], allocated: ) on slave 20150817-195212-2955812780-5050-29267-S2 from framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000
I0820 15:56:15.693084 32070 master.cpp:4290] Sending 1 offers to framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000 (demotask1) at scheduler-62a62438-bb19-4740-8428-7d632c958ef8@driverHost:33527

I0820 15:56:15.695425 32070 master.cpp:2884] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-O937 ] for framework 20150820-152021-1496194988-5050-32040-0000 (demotask1) at scheduler-62a62438-bb19-4740-8428-7d632c958ef8@driverHost:33527

**Mesos slave.Ip**

I0820 15:56:00.962321 32133 slave.cpp:4179] Querying resource estimator for oversubscribable resources

I0820 15:56:00.962446 32133 slave.cpp:4193] Received oversubscribable resources  from the resource estimator

I0820 15:56:15.967767 32128 slave.cpp:4179] Querying resource estimator for oversubscribable resources

I0820 15:56:15.967869 32128 slave.cpp:4193] Received oversubscribable resources  from the resource estimator
I0820 15:56:30.331955 32132 slave.cpp:3842] Current disk usage 18.49%. Max allowed age: 5.005413813717211days
I0820 15:56:30.969789 32132 slave.cpp:4179] Querying resource estimator for oversubscribable resources
I0820 15:56:30.969914 32132 slave.cpp:4193] Received oversubscribable resources  from the resource estimator
I0820 15:56:45.971680 32129 slave.cpp:4179] Querying resource estimator for oversubscribable resources
I0820 15:56:45.971807 32129 slave.cpp:4193] Received oversubscribable resources  from the resource estimator
I0820 15:57:00.972995 32134 slave.cpp:4179] Querying resource estimator for oversubscribable resources

Comment: How are you submitting your application?  Are you using the mesos-dispatcher?